# Optimal generation of Artifacts by maven build

Tags: maven, teamcity, artifactory, artifacts

We have a large project in a hierarchical manner with smaller projects inside, that is build using maven and then artifacts are published on to the artifactory. This process is automated by a teamcity run. This run takes a long time to build artifacts and publish to repository as all artifacts are regenerated and republished.

I was wondering, if I can set the maven to just build the artifacts whose associated files are modified after the generation of that artifact. I believe this can save a lot more time and cost on machines to build our codebase.
I would love to know about your experiences and possible solutions.

Though I know, this task can be done manually by building only specific projects that are modified. do we have any smart provision by maven to do that.

Comment: First how long is long? And how many modules you have? How long does it take to upload all those artifacts to your Repository Manager? This sentence: `This run takes a long time to build artifacts and publish to repository as all artifacts are regenerated and republished` i don't understand? What Maven version do you use?

Comment: it takes almost 3 hours and the modules are approximately 200 in a hierarchical manner. we are using Apache Maven 3.0.4.

Comment: Only 200 modules and taking 3 hours...how many tests are you running..can you give an approx number of lines of code (may be based on SonarQube?)...How long does the upload to Artifactory take? I'm working on a project with 420 modules (6500 tests) took 15 minutes...Are you using parallel build?

Comment: we have almost (4500 tests) and no the build is not in parallel since module have dependencies (this is a major issue) but of-course this is how project architecture is at the time .

Comment: That modules having dependencies is a default but not a reason not to parallelize...using things like this: `mvn -T 4...` ...if i would use single thread build it would make the build time about 40-45 minutes...Apart from that TeamCity has an option to only build changed modules (incremental modules) as Jenkins has...and i recommend you to check your infrastructure...cause it sounds very slow...measure the times of your build upload to artifactory etc. Do you use usual maven build or do you use plugins like maven-bundle-plugin etc. ?

Comment: Do you use [up-to-date plugin versions](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/) ?